# Html img 1 pixel line underneath

Tags: html, image

I am not a html programmer but I have to fix an urgent problem. Since this is a private project, I can't post the code here. But here is the obfuscated page source (Note: a href tag is created by Spring Security tag)

```
        <td width="359">
        <table style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:8px">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>

                        <a href="/login"><img src="/img/Login.gif" alt="Login" height="18" border="0" width="120"></a>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <a href="/newAccount"><img src="/img/newAct.gif" alt="new account" height="18" border="0" width="120"></a>  
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </td>
```

Above html code creates a 1 pixel shadow right under the second image. Please see attached picture and red arrow pointing to 1 pixel line.

[image: Screen shot]

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: It's not a shadow, it's a `text-decoration: underline` probably on the `a` tag. Use Firefox Firebug or Chrome Console `Inspect Element` to find out which element it is with that property. And, um, I'm just going to register a weakly voiced "boo to table-based layouts". Ahem.

Comment: Yeah, the table caused the text to be underlined....THAT's the ticket!

Comment: Thank you for your prompt help, I got it working changing the table to div.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="..." style="margin-top:0px;">
```

Comment: You should write something describing your code, simply code given is not an good answer :)